# Is there any built-in feature in @ngrx/data that first looks up the entity in the cache (by id/key) and, if not found, fetches it from the rest api?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-data

I would like to have a unified method in @ngrx/data which, for a given id/key, first looks it up in the store/cache and, only if it has not been fetched yet, calls the REST API.

So the first time that method will be called, it will trigger a REST call and all subsequent calls will get the entity from the store/cache.

If the entity needs to be refreshed, it will be done via other means (Websocket notification/manual action that will force the entity to be refreshed via the REST API).